# Where in Beijing can I get a Yellow Fever vaccine and certificate?

Tags: china, health, beijing

An [ICVP](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/6167/46787) can be required for international travel. Where can a non-Chinese national get a vaccine and certificate in Beijing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that one place is the [Beijing International Travel Healthcare Center](http://www.bithc.org.cn/) can give the yellow fever vaccine. I have contacted them to find out the procedure.

As of May 2018, they accept foreigners on for walk in appointments. You show up when they are open, they give you a medical exam costs 280 RMB (~$50) to make sure you are in good enough health for the vaccine. Then, they give you the vaccine and certificate for free. They say it takes about 3 hours between arrival and walking out the door with a certificate.

Note that I just found out that I don't need the certificate for my upcoming travel, so I have not personally tried this. However, this seems to be a hospital of high repute in China.

It seems the International Certificate of Vaccination or Prophylaxis (ICVP)  is called "国际疫苗接种证明书" in Chinese.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you so much for the link to their site and the information. Google translated the site, i put the pinion name in Didi (Jin'ao International Building) and it was effortless. Everything in the clinic is in both English and Chinese as are some of the staff. They are very comfortable with foreigners.

I do recommend getting here at 7:30am, as it can be a process if you need a physical: medical exam, ultrasound, xray, blood and urine test. Then there's a wait time for your physical to be reviewed. After the physical is reviewed you can get your vaccinations. Besides yellow fever, they offer every other vaccination as well, including the travelers medicine kit.

I'm getting three vaccines for 300rmb, which includes the physical listed above. The information above was such a huge help. Thank you for your post.

Comment: Michelle, this is fantastic. Thank you for confirming that this works!