# Are Australian passports expensive in comparison to other western / developed countries?

Tags: budget, passports, australian-citizens, price

I decided not to renew my passport before starting this trip because passports are very expensive in comparison to my income and my low travel budget.

But when asking people I find their passports in other countries are much more affordable than in my country. Typically Australian passports are in the range of roughly double the price friends have to pay in other developed countries or other western countries.

- Ordinary adult passport:
  `AUD` $238  (`USD` $212; `EUR` 161)
- Adult frequent traveller with more pages:
  `AUD` $358  (`USD` $320; `EUR` 243)

Is this a rip-off? Are most passports in "rich" countries so expensive or are they roughly half the price as the impression I have so far?

---

It's true I overlooked passport validity. That's the most important thing I've learned with this question. Assuming all passports have the same number of "visa pages" I should instead ask what the **"price per year or decade of validity"** is.

Comment: Data point, but not a complete answer: USA is $110, extra pages are offered on an as-needed basis for $82.

Comment: So, I'm sure your question is the second one / your title, but re "rip-off" - some folks would consider your passport to have more value than others.   Granted, the 'worth less' ones I'm thinking of are not US, UK, etc. and you do say 'developed countries' ... Just sayin', "rip-off" compared to what?

Comment: @hunter2: Rip off compared to other western and/or developed countries such as EU countries, USA, Canada, New Zealand, Japan, South Korea, Switzerland, Norway, Taiwan, Hong Kong. Capitalist democracies with similar economic status or cost of living etc. I think those are the ones that would make a "fair" comparison.

Comment: agreed, "rip-off" is subjective.  NZ passport may be more expensive, than say, South Africa, but it's a far more 'useful' passport (doesn't require as many visas when travelling), so its value is higher.

Comment: I believe NZ, UK, Canada, and Swiss passports are all more "useful" than Australian ones.

Comment: There's been a lot in the press in Australia in recent years about price gouging for instance CDs and Apple devices. Even the government has investigated. Yet the government may also be gouging us.

Comment: One point in Australia's defence: that price still gets you a 10-year passport, when many Western countries (eg. most if not all of the EU) have switched to only issuing 5-year passports.

Comment: You are lucky to be able to get a passport made abroad. That will cost more money, too. UK passports have to be made now in the UK since they closed all the facilities abroad, increasing the waiting time significantly.

Comment: The 10-year vs 5-year validity is the most salient point so far. This is offset though by those of us who fill pages in half the 10 years possible though.

Comment: The prices are always interesting. I see no rational reason for trains to be 4-times more expensive in Germany as compared to Poland, and even less for mobile Internet being about 5-times more expensive than in Austria. The fees for doing anything in public office are mostly dependent on how much public officers earn.

Comment: Right, that's what I figured. (And I know it's a tangent.)  I didn't have a firm position to begin with. MarkMayo's point is most of what I meant, but it's hard to put an absolute on these things - SA might be better for travel w/in Africa, ROC/Taiwan might be awkward in PRC/Mainland but otherwise great for East Asia ... etc etc // What about RFID tags? Is AUS doing those yet?  I'll get one for my upcoming renewal, though I'd rather not .. (Never mind, MM's got that covered, I see)

Comment: One person's "secure" is another person's "invasive surveillance".

Comment: Amen, brother.   If it wasn't for the second layer of foil ...

Comment: @jpatokal: AFAIK, only 5-year validity passports issued in EU are the ones issued to kids <13 years. Adult biometric passports have 10-year validity (I know first hand that's it's the case for Italy, Poland and Spain).

Comment: The fee for an Australian Tourist Visa (subclass 676) is AUD 230. So AUD 238 for a passport is not that bad in comparison :-)

Comment: @vartec: Not so, at least Belgium, Estonia, Finland, Luxembourg, Netherlands and Sweden only issue 5y passports.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biometric_passport#Countries_using_biometric_passports for a full list.

Comment: @jpatokal From March, validity will be 10 years in the Netherlands: 67 euro's: http://www.rijksoverheid.nl/onderwerpen/paspoort-en-identificatie/vraag-en-antwoord/wat-zijn-de-kosten-van-een-paspoort-of-nederlandse-identiteitskaart.html

Comment: It is still less than the cost of Turkish Passport (10 years - 533 Turkish Lira ~ around 190 Euro)

Comment: Wow! Any chance you can include a reference for this? Turkish is OK if you can't find an English ref.

Comment: There were a few comments on comparing the price of a passport to how _useful_ it is.  How about comparing it to how _necessary_ it is?  USA, Canada, and Russia:  Can go 1000s of miles w/o a passport.  (AUS too, but to what purpose?) Other countries: not so much.  You _need_ a passport to go somewhere interesting.  Therefore the value there is higher ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**They sure are!** Since I first asked this about 5 years ago, it has now become something easy to Google and is specifically covered by quite a few websites:

- [Australian passports are the ‘most expensive’ in the world](https://thenewdaily.com.au/news/national/2018/01/11/australian-passport-fee-increase/)
- [Most powerful and most expensive passports 2018](http://www.traveller.com.au/most-powerful-and-most-expensive-passports-2018-h0vy2f)
- [The world's most expensive passport is...](https://www.sbs.com.au/yourlanguage/hindi/en/article/2018/02/13/worlds-most-expensive-passport)
- [Australian passports are now the most expensive in the world with only Syria and Turkey coming close to the $282 charged - so why does it cost Aussies so much?](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-5264983/Australian-passports-expensive-world.html)
- [Australian Passports Now Most Expensive In The World](http://www.ladbible.com/news/news-australias-passports-now-most-expensive-in-the-world-20180113)
- [The most expensive passport in the world revealed - and it isn’t the UK](https://www.express.co.uk/travel/articles/915744/most-expensive-passport-in-the-world-australia)
- [Australian passports are the ‘most expensive’ in the world](https://www.reddit.com/r/australia/comments/7pzrob/australian_passports_are_the_most_expensive_in/)

Answer (score 6):

First, consider the value - it's a biometric, secure, popular passport.  It requires fewer visas than some other countries, and so the price isn't the only consideration here.

However, let's look at other [countries using biometric passports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biometric_passport#Countries_using_biometric_passports), and their costs, using some of your list from the comments:

- USA - $110 (According to LessPop_MoreFizz) (`EUR` 83)
- NZ - $144 and up, depending on urgency. (`USD` 112; `EUR` 85)
- South Korea - US$55.00. (`EUR` 41)
- Switzerland - CHF140. (`USD 150`; `EUR` 114)
- Netherlands - 49.33 Euros. (`USD` 65)
- UK - 77.50 quid. (`USD` 120.50; `EUR` 91)
- France - 89 Euros. (`USD` 117.50)

so comparatively, much of a muchness, although EU ones do seem to be a bit less.

As a New Zealander, a bigger issue is the length of validity - ours are only 5 years, which in some places means 4.5 years as you need 6 months left on your passport to enter certain countries.  We used to have 10 years, and [there is quite a public drive](https://www.facebook.com/NZ10years) to bring back the 10 year validity period.

Comment: @jpatokal er, UK ones are 10 years.

Comment: So is Germany, for >24 year olds, according to that wiki link. And France, and Spain (for certain ages).

Comment: And Malta and Ireland and Italy... ;)

Comment: It's worth noting that the cheapest on the list, Netherlands, only has a 5-year validity.  And I stand corrected, apparently there are still plenty of EU countries where you can get 10y passports. (Not including mine. Sigh.)

Comment: You assume biometric passports are a universal win. I know I'm not alone in hating them. They most certainly are not secure. Shortly after they were introduced some journalists tested one by hacking the data with Osama Bin Laden's likeness and had no problem using it! (http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2008/aug/06/news.terrorism)

Comment: "it's a biometric, secure, popular passport" - it doesn't explain the price. Production costs are tiny in comparison to final costs, and it's about most of the products.

Comment: The price table would be more useful if it included validity info. This was the key data point that I overlooked when asking/griping this question. Without that info it looks like Australian passports are pretty close to double the typical price for comparable passports. But if you're paying twice the price for twice the validity in every case then it's not a net loss. However if some of the others are also 10-year passports then the gripe is valid.

Comment: €80 in Ireland for a 10 year passport or €110.00 for the larger 66 page passport.

Comment: @ŁukaszL. In my case, applying for a passport involves seating for half an hour with a consulate employee (indeed, because he or she needs to take my fingerprints, etc.). Considering all costs involved (salary, bonus for being posted abroad, taxes, building security, office costs…), that's already a good chunk of the price. I pay my hairdresser a quarter of the price of a passport for about 15 min service.

Comment: Luxembourg passports seem to be extremely good value, it's only 30 € for 5 years and Luxembourg is not a cheap country.

Comment: @happybuddha not all, it's a relatively new thing. But yeah, SmartGate can then be used, although it's a bit more involved than just waving the passport - you have to answer some questions and have a photo taken.

Comment: It's not "much of a muchness" at all. An Australian passport is twice the price of an American one and 75% more than a British one; both of those are 10-year passports.

Comment: Spain, 10 years validity, 32 pages (24 empty pages): 26 euros (source spanish police: http://www.policia.es/documentacion/docu_esp/pasaporte/tasas.html)

Answer (score 3):

#### Comparing with the Italian Passport

**Both ordinary and frequent traveller Australian passports do indeed seem to cost more than the Italian passport**.

As of the [19th May 2010 the Italian government issues one single passport format for ordinary citizens](http://www.comune.padernodadda.lc.it/docinf.jhtml?param1_1=N10d4066cc7503eb879b). This is **an electronic passport, with biometrics, consisting of 48 pages with a 10-year validity**. [As of the 24th June 2014](http://www.esteri.it/mae/en/italiani_nel_mondo/serviziconsolari/documenti_di_viaggio/passaporto.html/) **it costs 116`EUR`**, (73.50`EUR` of processing fee + 42.50`EUR` for the actual cost of the booklet). This gives the following cost breakdown:

- 11.6`EUR` per year of validity
- 2.42`EUR` per page

We can now compare these values with the ones resulting from the Australian passport cost breakdown:

- Ordinary: 238`AUD` - ca. 166`EUR`

  - 16.6`EUR` per year of validity
  - 4.74`EUR` per year of validity
- Frequent traveller: 358`AUD` - ca 250`EUR`

  - 25.0`EUR` per year of validity
  - 3.73`EUR` per page

So yes the Australian passport wins on all criteria.

Comment: I think a fair comparison should take PPP into account :)

Answer (score 2):

The passports in Sweden are only 350kr, that equates to approximately 60 AUD. Even with the 5 year validity coming into question, doubling the cost it is still half the price. I couldn't believe how cheap the Swedish passports were when I checked - having recently paid for a new Australian one, I feel somewhat ripped off!