# Can I choose in which page of my passport is a visa going to be stamped?

Tags: visas, passports

When applying for a visa that takes up one whole page on a passport, is it possible to request it to be pasted on a certain page? I would like to reserve the front pages for my working visa, but I'll be applying for a Russian visa for travel before that.

Comment: Why would it not be possible?

Comment: Related: *[What can I do to prevent passport stamps being put on blank pages?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2939)*

Comment: Assuming you are referring to an app and not visa on arrival, for the UK, they will ignore it or worse, send your app to the Risk Assessment Unit.  Overall, not a recommended idea, but maybe Russia has different procedures.

Answer (score 1):

Most countries put the visa on the first available page that has sufficient room, which with a full page sticker/stamp would be the first blank page.  You can always ask and if you have a viable reason they may put it on another page for you.

Is there a specific reason why you want your work visa on the first page?  It doesn't really make a difference to immigration officals, as they are pretty adept at fanning through a passport and finding their country's visas.