# Are left pages of passports ever used?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, paperwork

I've just been to Cambodia.

For the visa rather than fitting it on the first empty page (the other side of the paper from a page with a few stamps) they instead skipped that and fit it on a new sheet of paper.

For the entry and exit stamps....they skipped the paper on the other side of the visa and instead went to a new paper.

The trip took 4 pages of my passport (albeit the 4th could still be used by countries where I need a stamp but not a visa)

I wonder about this; is this standard practice? Are left pages of passports ever used?

Comment: How did they fill four pages?  My Cambodia visas only take one page for the sticker and two stamps on another page.

Comment: Something must be afoot because all my US and Canadian visas (back when I needed such) were afixed to right pages. Stamps OTOH are all over the place.

Comment: Maybe because many consular officials are righthanded and so it is easier to put big stamps or stickers on the right page as your lefthand holds the passport open.

Comment: tom- they left one blank, then filled one with the visa, then left one blank, then stamped the next one.

Comment: "they left one blank, then filled one with the visa, then left one blank, then stamped the next one" -> so they only filled 1.25 pages?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I count 4 there.

Answer (score 7):

From many, many countries and borders, I find that it's often just down to the customs officer.

Sometimes they're incredibly precise, opening to the first spare page and clearly and carefully stamping the page.

Other times they just open, stamp, and hand it over.

I've got visas on both pages, back to back, facing both directions, in multiple passports.

Most likely, some just find it easier, but your passport has 25/48/50/100 pages for a reason - all can, and do get used.

(although some countries require you have x spare pages left, but that's a different story).

Related:

- [Can I choose in which page of my passport is a visa going to be stamped?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42804/can-i-choose-in-which-page-of-my-passport-is-a-visa-going-to-be-stamped?rq=1)
- [How do I decide whether to be worried about having enough blank pages in my passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27225/how-do-i-decide-whether-to-be-worried-about-having-enough-blank-pages-in-my-pass?rq=1)
- [What can I do to prevent passport stamps being put on blank pages?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2939/what-can-i-do-to-prevent-passport-stamps-being-put-on-blank-pages?rq=1)

Comment: I see. A small follow on- do they have to be in chronological order? Or are those skipped pages gone?

Comment: @theotherone definitely not - mine are all out of order, some upside down, left and right.  Order is not required.

Comment: They just stamp on whichever page they happen to turn to provided that there's space....