# How and where are Russian visas issued as separate documents?

Tags: visas, russia

[The website of Real Russia](http://realrussia.co.uk/Visas/Russian/Reading) states:

> There are two main formats of visa being issued by Russian consulates at the moment (in addition to **the rare separate paper version**)

As does [the website of RSPB Travel](https://russian-st-petersburg.com/other-services-russia/russian-visa-requirements-and-invitations/):

> A Russian visa is a special document either stamped to your passport **or issued on a separate paper**, that grants you a permit to enter and to leave the Russian Federation during a specified period of time.

I wonder in what circumstances you could get such a stand-alone Russian visa, and at what consulates?

Comment: I obtained such a separate paper visa from an application within Russia (already had a single-entry which was the sticker kind, got a new multiple-entry that came as a separate paper card).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As outlined in the [related](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/59391/getting-a-tourist-visa-sticker-not-put-into-passport-rather-as-a-separate-docum) question, there could be several reasons:

- The "visa" is a residence permit. In Russia it has the form of a passport booklet.
- Russia doesn't recognize the applicant's state of citizenship (for example, Kosovo), so they put their visa sticker on a separate piece of paper.
- You lost your passport after entering Russia and need to show proof of the legality of your stay.
- You don't have a passport at all, so there's no place where to put the visa (e.g. you're the British Queen).

Overall I wouldn't count on it as a regular tourist.