# Do Russian embassies tend to put visas on completely random passport pages?

Tags: visas, passports, russia

Re-posting it again because it was marked as a duplicate even though it wasn't.

Just got a Russian Transit visa. The visa pages in my passport are numbered 7-33, with only page 7 having stamps in it.

I sent a yellow post-it note to the visa application centre asking that the visa be put on page 8 ("please put the visa on page 8"). Still, the consulate put it on page 22.

I know most countries put visas on the first empty page, but **what about Russian embassies specifically**? The reason why it annoys me is because I truly want my passport to be neat and orderly, to make it easier to find stuff. Although it's the first time so far, I'd still like to know for future applications.

Could it even have been that my post-it note had the opposite effect? Would be good to know so I don't make that mistake again.

Comment: If I was the embassy employee, I would put the visa with an angle! like really tilted, just to make things even better for you :D

Comment: I know Russian embassies really really well, and for a long time too, going back to the Soviet era. Asking a Russian official to pay attention to your post-it note was naive, they will put it were it's easy to find FOR THEM. You're saying that that you can't find stuff in 33 pages? Then keep an external ledger about what's on what page. Honestly!

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis I LOL'd hard :D

Comment: @GayotFow I just prefer to have everything in order, i.e. page 1 first, then 2, then 3 (in this case 7, 8, 9) etc.

Comment: It's not necessary, I simply memorise it (just like I do my passport number and expiry date). What I asked was whether it's common for Russian embassies to use a random page, rather than the first empty one.

Comment: @Crazydre, it's common for Russian consular officials to do whatever they want, with a dose of bellicosity for good measure. I like them!

Comment: Yeah, tilted across two pages ;) Just jokking, but fun aside, I don't see how your question is much different from [this one](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/2939/32134). You have been around here long enough to know that the correct way to undo dupes is to edit and point out the differences to the supposed dupe and maybe make a case in meta or chat to help speed up. This is exactly what I want to see now, please edit your Q to point out **why it is not a dupe**.

Comment: Deleting your closed-as-dupe question and posting it again is not how things should work here IMHO. Besides, keep asking great questions and come back to answer after your trip :)

Comment: @mts This question is specifically about whether Russian embassies tend to do it like this, not just about handling These situations in any country. That's the difference

Comment: I can't say anything about Russia, but my experience in several other countries is that most officials flip open the passport, and if the page is empty, BAM!.  Usually NO attempt to check where else you've been and when.  Though likely the amount of scrutiny depends on which country's name is on the cover of the passport and which is on the sign above the official's desk.

Comment: I see, good to know! Guess the Russians like Sweden a great deal :P

Comment: Please don't re-post. Edit the old one.

Comment: @JoErNanO Except I deleted it

Comment: Can't you undelete it?

Comment: Really weak data point number, but both my Russian (and my Belarusian) visa were pretty much on the first empty page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear if they "tend to", but its clear that sometimes they will, as evidenced by your experience.

In general, immigration officals tend not to waste time doing more than finding the space they need before stamping/applying stickers etc.

Sometimes you can *ask* for a stamp or visa in a particular place, but a request is all that is.