# Can I travel to Italy with a permesso based on old passport?

Tags: italy, passport-renewals, permesso-di-soggiorno

I have permesso di soggiorno based on the visa in my old passport. Now I left Italy and changed my passport and my permesso is still valid. Now I wonder whether when I get back to Italy with new passport (without visa) and permesso based on the old passport will I have any problems. I went also to the Italian embassy they told me since I have active permesso they can't give me new visa. Could someone please answer?

Comment: Are you an Armenian citizen ? Is the visa in your old passport still valid ? Do you still have your old passport with the visa ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can travel to Italy with your current valid passport and your *permesso di soggiorno*.  You do not need your old passport or the old visa.

Your *permesso di soggiorno* is not "based on" a visa; it replaces the visa.  With a valid *permesso di soggiorno,* you do not need any visa.

See, for example, the [Schengen Borders Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex:32006R0562) Article 5(1)(b):

> 1. For stays not exceeding three months per six-month period, the entry conditions for third-country nationals shall be the following:
>
> (b) they are in possession of a valid visa, if required pursuant to Council Regulation (EC) No 539/2001 of 15 March 2001 listing the third countries whose nationals must be in possession of visas when crossing the external borders and those whose nationals are exempt from that requirement, **except where they hold a valid residence permit**;

(emphasis added)

Similarly, the permit itself allows you to remain in Italy as long as it is valid, and by implication to enter Italy at any time.

Comment: Is the permesso basically a type D visa ?

Comment: @blackbird it has the same legal effect as a type D visa, yes.  But unlike a type D visa, one can (must?) apply for and receive it in the country.

Comment: yes my visa is D type

Comment: the only thing that i worry is cause i remember when at the beginning i got my first permesso they told me that to other schengen countirens i can travel only with permesso and visa, only peremsso is not sifficent

Comment: @vahar it is not correct: Your permesso di soggiorno allows you to travel to any Schengen country, subject to the 90/180 rule for days spent in Schengen countries other than Italy. As you have learned, you can't even apply for a visa if you hold a residence permit.

Comment: ok thanks :) and just one curiosity, at the check point they always stamp on the corresponding visa or nearby (in this case italian visa), so since now the visa is absent should they stamp on a random page?

Comment: @vahar Yes, they'll generally stamp the first available page, but this is by no means automatic.  See http://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=visa+page, and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2939/what-can-i-do-to-prevent-passport-stamps-being-put-on-blank-pages

Comment: dear @phoog could i ask another question please. is it possible to re-enter italy with a permesso that will expire in 1 week? thanks in advance.

Comment: @vahar yes, that should be okay.

Comment: actually this one i was asking for my friends, she worries cause before leaving italy she forgot to apply for the new one and without the 'ascigarata' receipt  it might be a problem when re-entering. haha i told her the same that it should be ok, thanks a lot @phoog!