# Re-Enter in italy with Permesso di soggiorno

Tags: italy, student-visas, permesso-di-soggiorno

I was on student visa in italy I stayed for 3 months only in italy and got my permesso di soggiorno which is valid till 16 Jan 2024. My visa has just expired on 14th oct 2023. Now I want to travel from Pakistan to Italy on Permesso di soggiorno. Will I be able to enter italy smoothly or there will be any problem as I’m going back after 10 months later

Comment: @Willeke You're right, thanks. I have since found [this earlier Travel:SE question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/76832/can-i-travel-to-italy-with-a-permesso-based-on-old-passport?rq=1), which also came from an OP with no visa. The answer to that earlier question cites the Schengen Borders Code which exempts a permesso holder from holding (or even applying for) a visa. This convinces me that my earlier answer here was in error, and I have deleted it.

Answer (score 2):

A *Permesso di soggiorno* is a **residence permit**.

When you left Italy, you probably de-registered your residence there (or, at least, should have).

Under such circumstances a residence permit will often be cancelled.

Since you are no longer a resident, you should apply for a visitor visa.