# Does India require 2 blank passport pages, if you already have a visa in your passport?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, passports, india, passport-renewals

In common [with many folks here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2939/what-can-i-do-to-prevent-passport-stamps-being-put-on-blank-pages), I'm running rather short on blank passport pages. Specifically, I'm down to just 1 blank page left (plus a bunch of half-filled ones)

Looking [on the UK.Gov site for visiting India](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/india/entry-requirements), it states:

> Your passport must be machine readable, with 2 blank pages for your visa and valid for a minimum of 180 days at the time of your visa application.

Does the 2 blank pages apply only at the time you apply for your visa, or does it also apply when you travel?

I've spent a bit of time hunting around on the [Indian Bureau of Immigration website](https://boi.gov.in/), but I can't seem to find the answer. A check of Timatic via SkyTeam's website doesn't seem to help either.

Since I have a valid visa for India in my now-almost-full passport, is 1 blank page enough to travel on? Or do I require 2 blank pages (and hence an early passport renewal)?

Answer (score 2):

As usual, TIMATIC is the best source of information here.  It says (in part):

> Visa
>   Visa required.
>
> [...]
>
> Visa Issuance:
>   E-visas can be obtained before departure at https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/. Passengers using their e-visa for the first time must have:
>   - a passport with at least 2 unused visa pages, and
>   - a printed confirmation of the Electronic Travel Authorization (ETA).
>
> The Immigration officer stamps the e-visa in the passport with the expiry date of the visa and the number of entries allowed.

So, the answer is that you do not need two unused visa pages at the time of travel unless you are using an e-visa for the first time.

Comment: Note: on my passport, Indian immigration printed eVisa stamp in a page with other stamps, and the eVisa is just a normal (so small) stamp. So if you are getting low on empty pages, try to ask them to get the the new stamp (entry/exit) in an other page.